# Android fade in , fade out animation issue

Tags: android, animation, splash-screen, fadeout, fadein

I'm trying to customize the animation between two activities by fading out the splashscreen and fading in the main activity.

I trying two solutions, one with fade_in.xml and fade_out.xml where controlling alphas (0-1 , 1-0) and calling everything with overridePendingTransaction(fade_in, fade_out) and one with fade and hold like ni api demo (api/app/animation/fade);

The main problem is that the splashscreen (first animation ) is losing its alpha while sliding to the right as well and the second activity is appearing as wanted.

How is possible to lock the splashscreen to its original position and just making it fading out?

fade

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

hold

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="0"
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade, R.anim.hold);

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-animations-explained.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback for .fadeOut().